# " Prop `className` did not match" With Nested Styled Components

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I'm using Next.js and Styled Components, and I've configured them correctly in `next.config.js`.  Everything works great ... most of the time.

However, I have a table I'm trying to style, and when I base its styles off another component ...

```
const MyTable = styled(StandardTable)`background-color: white`;
```

I get the warning:

> Prop `className` did not match.

However, if I do the exact same component, but base it off a standard HTML table:

```
const MyTable = styled.table`background-color: white`;
```

I don't get the warning.  Also, if I manually copy/paste the CSS of StandardTable into MyTable, it works (with no warning).

Furthermore, I have other styled components (in the same file!) which are based off existing styled components, and use the same `a = styled(b)` syntax. They don't cause the warning either.

Can anyone explain why using this nested/inherited styling approach might cause this warning?  As far as I can tell, it doesn't have anything to do with server-side rendering (ie. what the warning is about).